# React Native Websocket to Python Socketserver communication

Tags: python, python-3.x, reactjs, react-native, websocket

I am trying to send a message from React Natives [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) object to a simple Python server built with the [socketserver](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socketserver.html) lib.

The communication is fine, however the message i am receiving from react native is not what i expected.

No matter what i send from React Native, i get the following message at the server:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
origin: {ip}
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: {key}
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Host: {ip}
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: okhttp/3.6.0
```

I have tried to use pythons socketserver before where it worked fine, but here i am clearly doing something wrong.

Any help, or pointers in a direction would be much appreciated.

I am sending the data from React Native to Python like this:

```
sendDataHandler = () =>{
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://myip:myport');
    ws.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
      ws.send('Hello Server!');
    });
  }
```

And my socketserver handler looks like this (just simple print example):

```
class RequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    
    def handle(self):
        
        data = self.request.recv(1024).decode("utf-8") 

        print(data)
        
        return
```